# Handed notice in at work & now have interview with a company owned by original employer!

Tags: management

OK - So I have handed my notice in at company A and applied for and set up an interview with Company B - Only thing is Company B is owned by Company A!

Should I just cut my losses & forget the interview as I have parted on bad terms with Company A which Company B is surely going to realise?

Any advice would be great - thanks

Comment: In general, do everything you can to avoid parting from any company on bad terms, and never hand in your notice before you have the next job lined up. That said, what harm would be done by going to the interview? At a minimum, it will be interview practice.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan They could find out half a year down the line and terminate him immedeatly upon finding out, leaving him jobless.

Comment: thanks for the comments, me leaving without a job lined up isn't up for debate here. It is a temporary position with Company B - one that I applied for in November and that they are now only recruiting for, it wasn't until earlier today I realised Company A owns 100% of Company B! However, they obviously haven't vetted me or spoken to my referee at Company A (who will give me an outstanding reference anyway as she has supported me throughout the whole mess with a certain group of line managers..) Thank you

Comment: As Patricia says, there's no harm in going to the interview. I'm not sure what else you need advice with as I don't see another question. So much of this depends on what happened at the original company, how you left and how closely related the two companies are that there isn't much else to say.

Comment: I don't want to turn up for an interview and have to lie through my teeth about why I have just handed in my notice with Company A I guess but thanks, I will still go along.

Comment: @StaciHarkness Don't lie, but put things in the least controversial light that is accurate. "I felt that my job at Company A was no longer a good fit for me."

Comment: I have already been through a short telephone interview and have said words to this effect which Company B were fine with... I am a classic worrier and have been through so much with Company A that I'm just feeling a bit down on myself I think - thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *"bad terms"* - That can include a multitude of sins?

Comment: What are the relative sizes of A and B?  If A is a giant MNC and B is one of the smaller companies, it's likely your experience at A won't matter.

Comment: I don't want to divulge too much here but I experienced a bereavement in my close family & my employer refused me time off for this - I eventually got 2 weeks off thanks to my Doctor and during this period was constantly badgered by my manager, and bombarded by abuse from co-workers on social media and in person. I involved my Union who arranged a grievance meeting about their behaviour. I consider this me leaving on 'bad terms' however successful my grievance meeting turned out to be. My previous manager backed me during this & has promised me a decent reference.

Comment: Company A is a MNC and took full ownership of Company B in 2013 - Company B is relatively small, serving only a small area of the UK with far less employees than Company A.

Comment: No offense, but if this is ever an option for you -- `have to lie through my teeth` -- then you have bigger issues than whether or not you should interview with a company that potentially may not like you.

Comment: I don't think going in there saying "I have handed my notice in with the company who owns your company because they bullied me during time off for bereavement!" - I can go in there and say as suggested by Patricia that my previous position was not a good fit... but this isn't the whole truth! Also given the environment it would only take one phone call for Company B to know I had to involve my Union over a dispute, as much as employers like good people they also like people who don't cause trouble regardless of whether they are in the wrong. Until now I kept my head down, its just unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just cut my losses & forget the interview as I have parted on bad terms with Company A which Company B is surely going to realise?

If you really have parted with Company A on Bad terms, then yes. Don't even bother. But, since you mentioned that you just handed in your notice, maybe try and do not part with A on bad terms, and then you might have a shot at working for B.

You cannot expect them not to find out very quickly, or worse, they find out half a year down the line and then you're unemployed.

Comment: The job with Company B is only a temporary contract of 5 months. There really is no going back with Company A, I have had to involve my union and this has been a long time coming, I have sweated it out for too long and something needed to change. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @StaciHarkness In that case I would cut my losses now and move on. If the breakup with company A got so messy, and the same people are involved in company B, seriously reconsider if you would even want to work for these people.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, at the time of applying back in Nov I wasn't thinking things would have become so messy so a transition to a different office with different managers etc wouldn't have been a problem. I don't know now if it would be a problem - they have entirely different managers and HR...

Comment: @StaciHarkness And the same owners. Owners that let this happen. Owners that will most likely fire you on the spot if they find out. In the best case its unnecessarily risky, and thats the best case.

Comment: so unfair isn't it?! They are the ones who have behaved poorly and yet I suffer, just proves what happens when you speak out against injustice at work! Hey ho, onwards and upwards! Thanks, appreciate your opinion.

Comment: @StaciHarkness Harping about unfairness only makes you mad for no reason. Power imbalance between employeers and employees will always be there. See it positively: You no longer have to deal with these people. And there are plenty of employers who wont screw you.

Answer (score 2):

Decent companies want good employees and not play childish games. And just because company A owns company B that doesn't mean that B has to follow every whim of company A. And if A is much bigger than B then there is a good chance that only a tiny part of A ever had anything to do with you.

If you go to an interview with B, turn out to be a good fit for the company, and then they find out that some random manager at A and his followers had a problem with you, then what happens depends very much on the relationship between the companies. Your prospective manager at B might even think "if that manager at A hates him, then Mr or Mrs Harkness can't be such a bad employee".

Consider that B being bought by A often means that B's employees don't like A very much at all. That if in six months time your old manager demanded that you were fired he might be told very politely and professionally that B's employment decisions are none of his business. And even in the USA, where your employer can lay you off at any time, you can quite likely sue successfully if someone else pressures your employer into doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you said is correct and you had mitigating reasons, along with the grievance process that I imagined came down on your side - I think you did not leave on *Bad terms*. You did not steal, beat people up. Just a different perspective in life.

Perhaps you feel that way that you left on bad terms - I think your manager unless (s)he is very childish will not think that.

I would go to the interview. If you get the job what is the probability that this will come up? Very small. Just be truthful but why bring up the subject in the interview. In the interview talk about your experience in the field etc.

People tend to let things go and have short memories.

If in the unlikely event (say a few months down the road), ensure that you have a good record to date. People do understand that sometimes personalities do clash and if you are getting on with the work, most people are reasonable and make their own minds up.

Comment: Thanks for the really good advice here, I think I am blaming myself for what's happened, need to remember what I have to offer, thank you.